NuSOAP PHP Codeigniter did not show elements/attributes of endpoint in Wizdler
I'm generating SOAP Server using NuSOAP with CodeIgniter 3 as framework, while the URL shows like this:
http://url/api?wsdl
It's perfectly fine and show the proper generated-WSDL, but when I use Wizdler extension to hit the endpoint from browser, it only show the first element / attribute like this example:
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <entryData1 xmlns="http://url/api">
            <req>[entryData]</req>
        </entryData1>
    </Body>
</Envelope>

I have this XML generated with NuSOAP:
<xsd:complexType name="entryData1 ">
 <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="req" type="tns:entryData"/>
 </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

And pointing on complex below:
<xsd:complexType name="entryData">
 <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="uniqueCode" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="fullName" type="xsd:string"/>
 </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

I tried to addComplexType and pointing the elements parameter to other complexType
using ['req' => ['name' => 'req', 'type' => 'tns:entryData']]
But the result is still the same.
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <entryData1 xmlns="http://uri/api">
            <req>[entryData]</req>
        </entryData1>
    </Body>
</Envelope>

What I want is, when I click the endpoint from wizdler, it show the full attribute without customize it every time I browse.
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <entryData1 xmlns="http://url/api">
            <req>
             <uniqueCode>[string]</uniqueCode>
             <fullName>[string]</fullName>
            </req>
        </entryData1>
    </Body>
</Envelope>

This is the register code:
$this->wsdl->register(
    $endpoint,
    array('req' => 'tns:'.$endpoint),
    array('return' => 'tns:'.$endpoint.'Response'),
    $this->namespace,
    'urn:'.$this->namespace.'#'.$endpoint,
    'rpc',
    'encoded',
    $arr['documentation']
);

